Angular 18 html2canvas changes default Url. Causes lazy load components not to load
I have been generating PDF with Html2canvas for the las 12 months. I resently upgrade to Angular 18. I changed all components to standalone. However when generation a pdf (the generating pdf worked ok)
I notice that when I tried to load another lazy load route it could not be loaded , because the url had been changed.
Proper url
http://localhost:4200/default-node_modules_angular_mate ... etc
Executed only Html2canvas from child lazy load component. Notice that 'reports was added
http://localhost:4200/reports/default-src_app_share ... etc
Because of the modified url all attempts to load any new components will failed. However
if a component already has previously loaded , then no problem
I executed a component that had only an Html2canvas and I was able to duplicate the problem.
public PublishRpt2(nativeElement: any, genericProofImage: GenericProofImage)
{
    html2canvas(nativeElement, { scale: 3 }).then((canvas) => {
        const imageGeneratedFromTemplate = canvas.toDataURL('image/png',1.0);
    });    
}


Out of desperation I upgraded NPM (to version 20...), reinstalled Angular 18 and every thing worked fine.
